# Opposite of "an everyday day"

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am wondering if there is an idiomatic expression that means the opposite of "an everyday day"

Can I say "a day of a lifetime"?

Comment: "a memorable/special day" (or any antonym of "usual/plain/ordinary/typical"). I am not sure how idiomatic the expression "an everyday day" is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom [**a red-letter day**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/red_letter_day) means a special, remarkable, or out-of-the-ordinary day.